# PHP PDO chamar procedure e logo depois select de tabela temporária

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Tenho uma procedure que cria uma tabela temporária e preciso fazer um select dela logo depois. Estou usando pdo e retorna sempre algum erro, no meu ultimo codigo dá erro 500 e não sei pra onde ir.

```
$proc = $this->conn->prepare("CALL proc_busca_disponivel(?)");
    $proc->bindParam(1, $id_evento, PDO::PARAM_INT, 4000);
    $proc->execute();
    $proc->closeCursor();

    $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT * from LISTA_DISPONIVEL");
    $stmt->execute();

    $res = $stmt->fetchAll(\PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    var_dump($res);
```

Não sou eu que faço o banco de dados. Se eu executo as queries no painel do mysql, retorna perfeitamente, por isso concluo que estou errando no pdo.
Também ativei e desativei buffler do pdo, pois havia indicado isso no erro em outras tentativas de criar o código, mas até agora não passei do erro 500.

```
$this->conn->setAttribute(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_USE_BUFFERED_QUERY, true); //ou false dá no mesmo
```

Comment: Quando você fecha o cursor `$proc->closeCursor();` o PDO libera o buffer contendo o resultado de sua consulta. `$proc->closeCursor();` deve ser usado caso você queira repetir mesma consulta.

Comment: Tirando o `$proc->closeCursor();` retorna o problema do buffle, mas setando para false cai no erro 500.